# Adding details to javascript picture slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, thumbnails, slideshow

Our team is currently working on completely redesigning our school's website and one of our projects currently underway is a lightweight photo slideshow which you can find [here](http://northviewhigh.com/index/frontPage/slideshow/FrontPageSlideshow.php).

Right now, when the user enters the space between two thumbnails, they all fade. What is the best way to organize them so that they all "unfade" when the user enters the general area of the thumbs? A div comes to mind, but I'm a little fuzzy on how we could implement it.

All help is much appreciated. None of us are particularly strong when it comes to styling with javascript, so this is a fun learning experience for us.

Many thanks,

Justian Meyer

Comment: I personally think it'd look nicer if only the one thumbnail being hovered over is highlighted and the rest remain muted...

Comment: Peter Ajtai: Thanks for the suggestion, we'll mess around with that option as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

html

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <img class="big" ..../>
  <div id="hover_area" onmouseover="startUnFade();">
    <img class="thumb" ..../>
    <img class="thumb" ..../>
    <img class="thumb" ..../>
  </div>
</div>
```

you can set postion of wrapper div on the page.

css

```
#wrapper {
  height: 420px;
  width: 660px;
  position: relative;
}
#hover_area {
  position: absolute; /* this will position your thumbnails relative to wrapper */
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5px; /* space at right and at the bottom */
}
/* and put you images one each other*/
#hover_area img.thumb {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px; /* 10px space between images */
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

And you shouldn't use inline styles create a `class` atribute and put style in css file.

Comment: This looks great, I'll give it a shot. They only thing that I don't want to change is the inline styles, however. Those are generated by our php scripts after it searches the images folder for the 1-6 images. We're trying to keep things simple for our graphic designers. The old system was a little flawed.

Comment: Actually, I think I understand what you're saying. I'll give that suggestion a thought as well :). I'll let you know how it goes. Many thanks!